# Use JNOSQL with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jnosql

I am looking for a common API in Java for NOSQL databases (similar to JPA for RDBMS) and found JNOSQL. However, I could not find a sample about JNOSQL and Spring Boot integration. Some samples I've found was based on Jakarta EE CDI only, e.g.: https://github.com/JNOSQL/oc1-hands-on-2019/tree/09ac19d196300a9c31d069d93e94e90b8740267d/nosql/src/main/java/jakarta/nosql/demo.

Is it possible to use JNOSQL with Spring Boot? If yes, is there a sample for it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Duy,

I have the same question/need.  I would appreciate hearing back from you on what you learned.

Here and/or my contact information is in my profile.

Comment: @K.hervey According to Otavio Santana (https://twitter.com/otaviojava), JNOSQL does not work with Spring/Spring Boot yet. My suggestion is you can use Jakarta EE instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of using JNoSQL with Spring Boot as far as I know:

1. You need to at least rewrite six implementation classes, four of them are basic jnosql beans, the other two are vendor specific (two per vendor, mongodb in my case). Mostly just simple inheritance to add public constructor so you can initiate them without cdi, some may require a little bit more works (like add parametered constructor to receive manually created dependencies). I can show you my configuration bean for those beans I mentioned above to give you an intuitive impression. Classes with their names start with Spring- are my rewrite of their original counterparts.

```java
@Configuration
public class MongoBeansConfig {
    @Resource
    private MongoDBDocumentManager documentManager;
    @Resource
    private EntitiesMetadata entitiesMetadata;

    @Bean
    public DocumentEventPersistManager springDocumentEventPersistManager() {
        return new SpringDocumentEventPersistManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public Converters converters() {
        return new Converters();
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringClassConverter springClassConverter() {
        return new SpringClassConverter(reflections());
    }

    @Bean
    public EntitiesMetadata springEntitiesMetadata() {
        SpringEntitiesMetadata metadata = new SpringEntitiesMetadata();
        metadata.setClassConverter(springClassConverter());
        metadata.init();
        return metadata;
    }

    @Bean
    public DocumentEntityConverter springDocumentEntityConverter() {
        return new SpringDocumentEntityConverter(springEntitiesMetadata(), converters());
    }

    @Bean
    public Reflections reflections() {
        return new Reflections();
    }

    @Bean
    public JNoSQLDocumentTemplate springMongoDBTemplate() {
        return new SpringMongoDBTemplate(documentManager, springDocumentEntityConverter(),
            springEntitiesMetadata(), converters(), springDocumentEventPersistManager());
    }
}
```

2. You need to write custom dependency resolver for @Inject (like @Autowired of Spring) and `@ApplicationScoped` (like @Component of Spring) along with `@Typed` (restricts which type to expose as bean) and at last create two empty beans of `Event` and `Event` type so `DocumentEventPersistManager` can work as normal.

By the way, I chose the 1st way since I don't want to mess with the dependency resolving mechanism of spring.